# Is it possible to match a sequence with multiple heads without using Condition

Tags: function-construction, pattern-matching, expression-manipulation

Suppose I have:

```
expr = Times[2, a[x,r], a[y,1], c[z,0,0], d[w,m]];
```

If I want to match a sequence of expressions with the same head `a`, I would use a `PatternSequence` like this: `__a`,  *e.g*.:

```
 expr /. Times[rest___, subExpr__a] :> myfunc[Times[subExpr]]
```

> ```
> myfunc[a[x, r] a[y, 1]]
> ```

But what if I want to match a sequence of expressions with multiple heads `a` *or* `d`?  The only way I know how to do this is by using `Condition`:

```
expr /. Times[Longest[rest___], subExpr__] /; FreeQ[Times[rest], _a | _d] :> myfunc[Times[subExpr]]
```

> ```
> myfunc[a[x, r] a[y, 1] d[w, m]]
> ```

My expressions are very long and complicated and ideally, I'd like to avoid having to use `Condition` which requires calls to the Kernel.  Is there a way to accomplish my task purely with the pattern-matcher?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using `BlankSequence`, use `PatternSequence`:

```
expr /. Times[rest___, subExpr : PatternSequence[___a, ___d]] :> myfunc[Times[subExpr]]
```

> ```
> myfunc[a[x, r] a[y, 1] d[w, m]]
> ```

The orderlessness of the pattern sequence is ensured by the `Orderless` attribute of `Times`.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of pattern-matching the expressions you want to keep, you could also remove the ones you do not want to keep:

```
myfunc[Replace[expr,x_ /; Not@MemberQ[{a, d}, Head@x] -> Sequence[], {1}]]
```

This approach should be faster than using pattern matching using multiple blanks. It also works with other expression heads than `Times`.